# Mostrar vueltas de un for en intervalos de tiempo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, bucle-for

Lo siguiente es más que todo una consulta. Tenemos ciclo for sencillo:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
  echo $i."</br>";
}
```

Como ya sabemos a la hora de ejecutar éste codigo se van a mostrar ya de una vez todos los resultados en éste caso un conteo del 1 al 10, lo que quisiera saber es con cual lenguaje, quizás **AJAX** o **JAVASCRIPT**, o alguna **funcion** de **PHP** podría mostrar cada una de las vueltas del **ciclo for**, es decir que s emuestre el 1, luego el 2, y así, se que ya parece algo de **AJAX** pero es que no lo manejo mucho, pero igual estoy abierto a sugerencias con este lenguaje, el punto es que hayan intervalos de tiempo entre cada vuelta del **for**, ya que estoy manejando un **for** que requiere de muchas vueltas y el navegador se cuelga, y quería ver si esta podía ser una solución.

Comment: AJAX  no es un LENGUAJE, sino una tecnología para hacer comunicación asíncrona entre el cliente y el servidor

Comment: Si entiendo bien, lo que pretendes se puede hacer con las funciones de control de salida: http://php.net/manual/es/ref.outcontrol.php. Por otro lado pienso que algo no estas haciendo bien o que has podido tomar un camino inadecuado, pero sin más contexto no podría orientarte. Cuantos registros vas a mostrar? Cuanto tarda en ejecutarse el Script? Cual es la finalidad?

Comment: @Xerif La cantidad es variante, pero siempre serán mas de 1000, lo que busco es que los registros no se muestren de un solo golpe, pues a veces eso ralentiza el navegador cuando son demasiados registros.

Comment: @Jalkhov Sinceramente cualquier sistema que muestre a n usuario mas de 100 registros sin paginación, pienso que tiene un mal diseño asi como un problema, mi recomendacion es que replantees tu estrategia. Lee sobre paginación y si tienes problemas a la hora de llevarlo a cabo puedes plantearnos el problema concreto.

Answer (score 1):

podrías intentar con una función recursiva en Javascript:

```
function recursiva( i, maximo )
{
    if ( i > maximo ) return;
    console.log(i)
    i = i + 1;
    setTimeout( function(){ recursiva(i, maximo); }, 1000 );
}

recursiva(1, 10);
```

Comment: Bueno el código @Carlos Quintero, ¿Cómo podría llevar ésto a php?